# Shopify XML API Not Updating the Tracking Number

Tags: xml, shopify

I am trying to create a new fulfillment for an order using the Shopify API. Here's a sample XML request that I’m sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fulfillment>
    <tracking-number>1Z0000000300002879</tracking-number>
    <notify-customer type="boolean">false</notify-customer>
</fulfillment>
```

I get a 200-OK after POST /admin/orders/12345678/fulfillments.xml. The order gets updated to `fulfilled` correctly, however the tracking number field is still blank. This happens for every order I update; the status is `fulfilled` but the tracking number is never set. Ideas?

Comment: You should be getting a `201 Created` response if you're creating a new fulfillment correctly. Can you post the actual ids you're using along with your API key? That will help us debug the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The {"line_items" => ["order_item_id1", "order_item_id2", "order_item_id3"],

is different than the API documentation which says the line_items are line_item objects not just strings of the order item id.

```
"fulfillments": [
{
  "created_at": "2012-09-28T11:50:06-04:00",
  "id": 255858046,
  "order_id": 450789469,
  "service": "manual",
  "status": "failure",
  "tracking_company": null,
  "tracking_number": "1Z2345",
  "tracking_url": "http://www.google.com/search?q=1Z2345",
  "updated_at": "2012-09-28T11:50:06-04:00",
  "receipt": {
    "testcase": true,
    "authorization": "123456"
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "fulfillment_status": null,
      "grams": 200,
      "id": 466157049,
```

I'm trying the latter but have to wait until another order comes in because I get 'Unprocessable Entity' for a duplicate fulfillment.

Not sending any line_items causes the tracking number to be ignored but the order fulfilled.

Answer (score -1):

The fulfillment expects a list of line_items that should be marked fulfilled with that tracking number. You aren't sending any, so none can be marked fulfilled.

Here's a rails example I've got on hand that should get you in the right direction.

```
@payload = {"fulfillment" =>
    {"line_items" => ["order_item_id1", "order_item_id2", "order_item_id3"],
    "notify_customer" => true,
    "tracking_number" => order.tracking_number
    }}.to_json
```

Comment: Passing no line items causes all items to be marked as fulfilled (or at least it should)

Comment: I updated my XML as follows:                                                

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<fulfillment> 
    <tracking-number>1Z0000000300003145</tracking-number>
    <notify-customer type="boolean">false</notify-customer> 
    <line-items type="string">235914468</line-items> 
</fulfillment>

                                                                          
The order was successfully fulfilled however the tracking number is still not being saved with the order. In addition the customer was notified even though that value is clearly False.

Comment: I found my problem, my XML wasn’t actually being sent as part of the httpPost request. Once I fixed that all is well.